# Omniauth/Bundler: "Could not find oauth-0.5.6 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have put the following line in my gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth', '~> 2.0.4'
```

Which is the current version of [OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth). Then I ran

```
bundle install
```

Now when I try, for instance, to generate a controller, I get following error message

```
Could not find oauth-0.5.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

I find the folder even in my rvm gemset with the correct version!

What the heck is wrong? : /